# Simplify multiple (non nested)foreach loops in c#

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I have a JSON object:

```
"Cars": {
 "Honda": {
   "CRV": [

     { "index": 1, "Color": "Black" },
     { "index": 2, "Color": "White" }

    ],
    "Civic": [

     { "index": 1, "Color": "Blue" }

    ]
   },
  "Toyota": {
   "Corolla": [

     { "index": 1, "Color": "Black" }

    ],
    "Camry": [

     { "index": 1, "Color": "Blue" }

    ]
   },
  "GM": {
   "Chevrolet": {

     "Cruze": [

       { "index": 1, "Color": "Blue" }

    ]

    }
 }
```

I have to store this information in a table. Right now I am parsing each List in a separate for each loop like this:

```
 foreach (CarInfo info in Cars.Honda.CRV)
  {
                //storing in table
  }
  foreach (CarInfo info in Cars.Honda.Civic)
  {
                //storing in table
  }
 foreach (CarInfo info in Cars.Toyota.Corolla)
  {
                //storing in table
  }
```

and so on.
Is there a way I could optimize this code? (Given is just an example, the actual JSON is more extensive and had made me write way too many foreach loops)

The method for storing the info in table is different for each Car make.

Comment: Create a method you can call three times, once with `Cars.Honda.CRV`, `Cars.Honda.Civic`, and once with `Cars.Toyota.Corolla`? Put the loop in that method...

Comment: Get away from having specific fields for manufacturers and models. This should be in a Dictionary.

Comment: Have you considered using a library such as Json.NET - Newtonsoft.Json to handle the deserialisation from Json for you? If it suits your purposes, it might allow you to do away with all of the foreach loops.

Comment: @Sepia, I am using NewtonSoft to extract deserialize the JSON into an object. The 'Cars' object in foreach loop is that deserialized object.

Comment: Ah, okay. If the 'storing in table' code is identical in each of the loops then Jon Skeet's solution would be best. If it is different, then I think seeing examples of what some 'storing in tables' do would be helpful.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's not just those three for loops, in real code there are around 15 such foreach loops. In that case I would need to call the method 15 times.

Comment: are the methods to your 'storing in table' different for each of the make/model

Comment: @Jawad Yes actually

Comment: @dokyalashot see my response .. Create Dictionary via recursive method, save for each list separately using switch statement.

Comment: @dokyalashot: So you could create an array with the 15 values in, then loop and call the method 15 times that way. Even 15 method calls would be better than 15 foreach loops though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no control over the input JSON, here's an approach similar to my last recommendation that parses up the incoming JSON, including support for GM submodels.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // parse the JSON results of the API Call
    JObject apiResult = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("JsonBlock.json"));
    // iterate through the models
    foreach (var model in apiResult["Cars"].Children<JProperty>().Select(i => i.Name))
        // GM cars have a submodel
        if(model.Equals("GM",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) 
        {
            foreach (var submodel in apiResult["Cars"][model].Children<JProperty>().Select(i => i.Name))
                AddCar(submodel,apiResult["Cars"][model][submodel]);
        } 
        else
            AddCar(model,apiResult["Cars"][model]);            
}

static void AddCar(string model, JToken cars)
{
    switch(model)
    {
        case "Honda":                    
            // do honda things
            break;
        case "Toyota":
            // do toyota things
            break;
        case "Chevrolet":
            // do chevy things
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the source data format under your control?

- As 3Dave mentioned, you'll be much happier if the car make and model are values instead of keys.
- I might add that you currently have a single "Cars" object.  You might find this much easier to manage if you have an array of "Car" objects, each of which has their various attributes internal.

```
{ "Cars": [
  { "make": "honda",
    "model": "CRV",
    "attributes": ["index":1,"color":"blue"]
  },
  { "make": "honda",
    "model": "CRV",
    "attributes": ["index":2,"color":"white"]
  },
  { "make": "honda",
    "model": "Civic",
    "attributes": ["index":1,"color":"black"]
  }
]}
```

This makes it trivial to collapse your iteration down to a single foreach loop, then handle the different method for storing in a table within a subroutine:

```
void AddAllCars()
{
  foreach (var car in Cars)
    AddCar(car);
}

void AddCar(CarInfo car)
{
    switch(car.Make)
    {
      case "honda":
        // honda-specific stuff
        break;
      case "toyota":
        // toyota-specific stuff
        break;
    }
}

(Note that even if you can't reformat into an array of Cars, you can still make big improvements by changing make and model to values instead of keys)
```

Comment: This is a very good solution,but the problem is that json is coming from an API call, really can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this... Recursive Approach since your classes dont line up with Cars/Make/Model, you have Cars//Make/Model.

1. Parse the Json to JObject
2. Create a dictionary for each *Make* so you can save them separately via your distinct process

```
    public static Dictionary<string, List<CarInfo>> GetCarInfo (JObject jObject)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<CarInfo>> list = new Dictionary<string, List<CarInfo>>();
        foreach (var property in jObject.Properties())
        {
            var thisProp = jObject[property.Name];
            if (thisProp.Type.ToString().Equals("Array"))
                    list.Add(property.Name, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CarInfo>>(thisProp.ToString()));
            else
                GetCarInfo((JObject)jObject[property.Name]).ToList().ForEach(x => list.Add(x.Key, x.Value));

            }
        return list;
    }

    public static void SaveData(string key, List<CarInfo> value)
    {
        switch (key.ToUpper())
        {
            case "CRV":
                // save it the CRV way
                break;

            case "COROLLA":
                // save it this way
                break;

            default:
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to figure out which car it is..");
        }
    }
```

**Usage in Main**

```
    var cars = JObject.Parse(json);
    Dictionary<string, List<CarInfo>> carInfos = GetCarInfo((JObject)cars["Cars"]);
    foreach (var carInfo in carInfos)
        SaveData(carInfo.Key, carInfo.Value);
```

**Note**

I noticed that your json object doesnt really follow the same standard. Your GM has two parent companies when Honda, Toyota have one.

**Suggestion**

Only thing I would suggest to make the code look and perform better is to update the way you make a call to update / add to DB. Currently, you have one call per type which is what defines your foreach loops. If you can make one generic method to save "CarInfo" with another argument that defines "CRV", or "CORROLLA", it would make things Much easier for you.

Comment: Yes.. that's how the json is coming as a reponse from the API call.

Comment: If you can make a generic approach to how you save your data (with an argument defining which Make.Model you are saving, you can save yourself a Lot of time by simply calling save to database ONE time